# how do i run a Script inside django?

Tags: python, django

```html
C:\Users\Qasim\Desktop\translator>python manage.py runscript text
No (valid) module for script 'text' found
Try running with a higher verbosity level like: -v2 or -v3

C:\Users\Qasim\Desktop\translator>python manage.py runscript text -v2
Check for django.contrib.admin.scripts.text
Check for django.contrib.auth.scripts.text
Check for django.contrib.contenttypes.scripts.text
Check for django.contrib.sessions.scripts.text
Check for django.contrib.messages.scripts.text
Check for django.contrib.staticfiles.scripts.text
Check for news.scripts.text
Check for rest_framework.scripts.text
Check for django_extensions.scripts.text
Check for scripts.text
No (valid) module for script 'text' found
```

```html
#text.py
from news.models import News

def run():
    #all news
    deleteAll = News.objects.all()

    #delete all news
    deleteAll.delete()
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? What is the contents of text.py? When you say you want to "run a script inside Django" what exact behavior are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: i want to delete all the objects stored in database, i put the test.py code now above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For something like this, I would recommend creating a custom management command. This will allow you to run the code using `manage.py <command name>` like you are trying to do.

Docs are at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-management-commands/

So you would start by adding a `management` folder in your application's directory, then add a `commands` folder inside the `management` folder.

Inside the commands folder create a file for your command - something like `delete_all_news.py`. You will run the command using the name of the file (without the `.py` extension) - so if you name the file `delete_my_stuff.py` you would run it with `manage.py delete_my_stuff`. Don't begin the filename with an underscore or you will not be able to run it from the command line (you would use these files for supporting files that you didn't want to act as actual commands - not necessary in your case).

The contents of that file could be something like the below (obviously in production you would want exception handling and some kind of notification/logging that the command succeeded or failed)

**news/management/commands/delete_all_news.py**

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
from news.models import News


class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Delete all news items from database'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        News.objects.all().delete()
```

Then run from the command line with `manage.py delete_all_news`

Also note that you can chain the `delete()` call onto the `objects` filter - no need to read `objects.all()` into a variable and then perform the delete, you can do it all in one statement if you prefer.

Comment: Am very thankful,i followed the steps, it was good with no bugs , my problem is solved, thank you @jim

Comment: Glad I could help!